# php url encode(previousUrl) issue

Tags: php, url, encode

I have the php page with url that include the path of my previous url with encoding string. But it has error when open this url as there is some specified characters such as space ....

```
url="www.xxxx.com/home/".encode($previousUrl)
```

Comment: you might want to try PHP's [build a url function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php)

Comment: can you please share previousUrl.

Answer (score 1):

Try cleaning the url use the below function :

```
function clean($string) {
    $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
    $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.

    return preg_replace('/-+/', '-', $string); // Replaces multiple hyphens with single one.
}
$encUrl=clean( $previousUrl); //pass the url to clean
```

Comment: It seems cannot as $previousUrl is needed to redirect back to previous url. If I amend the previousUrl, would it still redirect back correctly??

Comment: The clean function will just remove the invalid characters from the provided url and if the url is a valid path and if your redirection code is valid it will redirect

Comment: Hi, I have used your case. It is not correct as when I use cleaned url to redirect to this url. It is unrecognised as I see this is different from the previous Url string.

Comment: Actually, I will get the url and assign to the variable and add it to the next url in the end as parameter with '/' separater.

Comment: can you provide the example value of previousUrl which is causing error and what should be ur output look like that will help a lot

Comment: www.xxxx.com?prevURL=<?php echo urlencode(current_url()); ?>